# Time-series clustering with python

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have a multiple time series data of different customers (around 10k customers, for 100 days). I want to cluster this data into 5-10 groups.

However, I don't have any tips about the time series clustering.
Is the K-means works for them?
Any python package works for this data?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You could try K-Means based on ***Dynamic Time Warping*** metric which is much more relevant for time series (see [`tslearn` tuto](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/clustering.html)). Saying that, there is an interesting discussion about [Dynamic Time Warping Clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131281/dynamic-time-warping-clustering) that you could read with a [lot of references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/131284/242848) that give time series clustering code examples.

Another common approach would be to extract relevant features from your time series and apply clustering techniques to them (see [`sklearn` clustering page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)). You could extract a lot of [common features for time series](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/list_of_features.html) using [`tsfresh`](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) python package.

**Other readings**
[Measuring the distance between time series, *Richard Moeckel, Brad Murray*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167278996001546?via%3Dihub)
[Alternate distance metrics for two time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185912/alternate-distance-metrics-for-two-time-series)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest customer segmentation which is topic well studied in marketing analytics. You might have a lot to search with those key words.

However here is an example using PCA for clustering :
https://www.kaggle.com/zonnalobo/timeseries-segmentation-and-forecasting